# google apps script traverse object

Tags: javascript, object, google-apps-script

I've searched and searched but cannot find a better way to search through a JSON object and return a nested object that corresponds to a specific key.

I've found examples that work in javascript but when I try to use that code in Google Apps Script I find that some of the function/modules are not supported.

deeply The script below works where objRet is a global variable but I wondered if there was a better way to do it?

```
var objRet;

function blahblah() {
    traverse(api_info, "EarningsRates");
    // use this.objRet to process code
}


function traverse(json, keyData) {
   var keyData = keyData;
   var json = json;

   if (Array.isArray(json)) {
        json.forEach(traverse);
    } else if (typeof json === 'object') {
       Object.keys(json).forEach(function(key) {
            if (key === keyData) {
              this.retObj = json[key];
            } else {
               traverse(json[key], keyData);
            }
        });

    }

}
```

I found this and would love to get it working but no luck with Google Apps Script

This function implements DFS: (depth first search)

```
function findDFS(objects, id) {
  for (let o of objects || []) {
    if (o.uuid == id) return o
    const o_ = findDFS(o.children, id)
    if (o_) return o_
  }
}
```

And BFS:(breadth first search)

```
function findBFS(objects, id) {
  const queue = [...objects]
  while (queue.length) {
    const o = queue.shift()
    if (o.uuid == id) return o
    queue.push(...(o.children || []))
  }
}
```

Comment: If some errors occur in your script, can you provide them? And also if you provide the input and output you want as a sample, it will help users think of your solution.

Comment: GAS doesn't support the let keyword to declare a variable or rest / spread operators. That was added in ES6 - GAS is ES5-based